# how much RPS(request per second) can be achive with apify cheerio, apify basic crawler

Tags: apify

how many maximum request per second can be achive with apify cheerio and basic crawler. An it be used for the simulation of ddos attack.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't really any limit until you hit the limit of your CPU, memory, and/or network. Simply increase maxConcurrency as you wish. My record was about 4000 concurrency.

But please use this only for sources that gave you consent. Taking sites down is not what Apify is for.